# Is it a bad idea to have a TeamCity webserver instance also act as a build agent?

Tags: build-automation, amazon-ec2, cloud, teamcity

I'm building an Amazon EC-2 cloud-based build server for my personal development projects using Team City Professional. I only intend to use it of an evening and my project builds are going to be quite small.

At this stage, is there a good reason why I should go for two servers:

- one hosting the Team City website
- another configured as the build agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many servers you need or which instance type to use heavily depends on the nature of your projects and the number of resources they utilize during the build -- add to that how fast you want your builds to be done and how much money you want to spend.

Generally, it sounds like you want a EBS-based instance so you can stop and resume at any time. I don't see how two servers right from the start would do you any good and start with one and scale up by going to a larger instance size before adding a second server to the mix.

If you keep the server online only for a few hours a day, then the cost should be reasonable anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Scaling up and then out seems pragmatic. I was worried that it would be poor separation of concerns to have everything on one box (that I would in some way be polluting the web server with build server stuff). As you say, just deal with it when/if it becomes a problem.